# Android studio how to pass Array data to another activity's TextView?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I am new to learning Array in android studio. Please show me some examples in details. I have write an example here and I want to display the Array data from MainActivity into second_page activity .

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String my_array[]={"dog","cat","tiger"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void next_page(View view){  
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,second_page.class);
    intent.putExtra("my_array_next", my_array);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

second_page.java

```
public class second_page extends MainActivity {

TextView get_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_page);

    get_data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    // coding here to display the array data 
    // sth like   abc.setText(display_array_data);

}
```

Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: i think you should read the basics of using Intents http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: try my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/38349785/3981656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `second_page.java`, receive the array you pass via `Intent` and set it to your `TextView` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String[] array = intent.getStringArrayExtra("my_array_next");

    // TextView display a String so you should convert your Array to String
    String str1 = Arrays.toString(array); 
    get_data.setText(str1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send a String-array from one Activity to another this can be done in the Intent.

> In ClassA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB);
String[] my_array = new String[]{"dog","cat","tiger"};
intent.putExtra("myArr", my_array);
startActivity(intent);
```

> In ClassB:

```
public void onCreate() {
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("myArr");
}
```

this may helps you

Answer (score 0):

First take the array:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
List array;
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    array= intent.getExtras().getBoolean("my_array_next");
}
```

Then print

```
get_data.setText(array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sending Class:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB);
String[] myStrings = new String[] {"test", "test2"};
intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Reciving Class:**

```
public void onCreate() {
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Second activity:

```
String[] array=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("my_array_next");
```

I think you need to go through basics, go to https://developer.android.com/index.html to get started.